# Why is the title being repeated?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am getting the current playing song, and capturing the title and artist, and storing it in parse. For some reason, when the song plays, the program adds 4 or so of the same title/artist. I instead just want one. How do I fix this?

[my objects as seen in the parse data browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsCOw.png)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
}

func getNowPlayingItem() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

    if  let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem  {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artisttest = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
        if let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String{
            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")
            let object = PFObject(className: "MasterSongs")

            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)
                    // print(self.Parsearray)
                }

                if self.Parsearray.contains(title!){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{
                    objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = artist

                    objectPointer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if(error != nil){
                            print(error)
                        }else{
                            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }else{

            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")

            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                    // print(self.Parsearray)
                }

                if self.Parsearray.contains(title!){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{
                    objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = "No artist found :("

                    objectPointer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if(error != nil){
                            print(error)
                        }else{
                            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must be adding it to Parse for it to appear in parse, I see you have a loop. So possibly its occurring there. But the point where you decide - do I have this object if NO add to Parse or YES don't add it is where the problem is occurring.

Comment: The loop is just retrieving the titles in the db, and comparing it to the current playing song, and if the current playing song is found in that array, then it wont be added, if it isnt then it will be.

Answer (score 1):

From the evidence, there's a good chance that the function `getNowPlayingItem` is being called several times rapidly.  It launches queries, a handful of which complete before anything is saved.  Those query completions (with no saves done yet) launch a handful of saves and you get a handful of objects.

Check this by printing a message at the start of the method and just before `saveInBackground` paying attention to the timestamps on the console.

If I'm right, the fix is simple: (a) find out why the method is being called so many times and fix that, or (b) add a boolean instance variable to the enclosing class, call it something like `busySaving`.  At the start of the method, bail out if `busySaving` is true, otherwise set it to true an carry on.  Change your `saveInBackground()` to `saveInBackgroundWithBlock()` and reset the `busySaving` flag in the completion block.

**EDIT**
Now we see why it's being called repeatedly: because the notification is being received repeatedly.  One way to fix (idea (a) above) would be to stop observing that notification (NSNotificationCenter removeObserver) at the start of `getNowPlayingItem`.  Then, since you want to get subsequent notifications, re-add yourself as an observer after the save, using `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`.  Notice this is different from `saveInBackground` [see here for reference](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveInBackgroundWithBlock:).

Idea (b) above still applies as well, if you prefer.

Comment: My sentiments exactly. The method itself doesn't show signs of saving 4 times. @tman0542 you should check elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I edited my code to include where the function is being called. I still don't know what you mean by the `saveInBackground` is not completing before the method is called.

Comment: @danh, you are correct, the method is being called more than once, how do I fix it? http://puu.sh/lF6RV/21d18dca6b.png

Comment: First understand what's happening:  it gets called with no matching objects on the server, so it decides to save one.  **Before** that save *which is done in the background* finishes, it gets called again.  The query finds no matches again *because the save hasn't finished*.  Make sense?  Please see the last paragraph of my answer for the fix.

Comment: Tried to customize that fix advice a bit, now that we know the source of the multiple calls.

Comment: I updated my code to your edit for part b by removing the observer and adding it again, but it is not working. I am running into the same problem

Comment: Can you add a few more print statements: (a) "entered function" before removeObserver, (b) before every saveInBackground and in every save completion block.  Please post the log output, too.  Also noted: it looks like you added a big chunk of else code, and in it, another saveInBackground without completion block.

Comment: I added a couple statements (updated the code above). Here is what the console says. http://puu.sh/lKPTt/22bd7fab5e.png

Comment: So what's your opinion on that console output?  To me its evidence that the code is doing what you want it to do (saving the first time, but not the second time when it finds the saved objects).  Your job is to correlate that output with the objects you're seeing in the data. To do a thorough job debugging, you should have log statements before every parse call and in every completion block, timestamps on the console output, when logging, try to log meaningful stuff, like the object IDs of the objects being saved or found, etc.